# When I close the popup and then click the back button on my mobile then my app gets close in qml

Tags: qt, qml

```
Page{
id: app
Popup  {
                   id: popup1
                   background: Rectangle {
                       implicitWidth: 400
                       implicitHeight: 200
                       Row{
                           topPadding: 40
                           leftPadding: 10
                       Text {
                           id: warning
                           text: qsTr("Are you sure you want to exit the App ?")
                       }
                       }
                       Row{
                           topPadding: 100
                           leftPadding: 60
                           Button {
                               id: yes_btn
                               text: qsTr("YES")
                               onClicked:
                               {
                                   Qt.quit();
                               }
                            }
                           Button {
                               id: no_btn
                               text: qsTr("NO")
                               onClicked:
                               {
                                   popup1.close();
                               }
                            }
                       }
                   }
              }
Keys.onBackPressed: {
            popup1.open();
    }
```

}

On back button press on my phone popup1 opens and when I close the popup and again press the back button then instead of opening popup my app get closed. how to prevent that?

Comment: Where is that piece of code situated?

Comment: I have edited the code please check

Comment: maybe this is helpfull? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31333638/prevent-qapplication-app-from-closing-if-a-service-is-running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that might interest You is using the `onClosing` signal that is sent every time You press the back button.

```
onClosing: {
   close.accepted = false
   if (popup1.opened)
       popup1.close()
   else
       popup1.open()
}
```

This code should make your popup open when the back button is pressed and also close it when it is opened.